# Lambda calculus - evaluating these lazy parameters

Tags: computer-science, lambda-calculus, computer-science-theory

I'm reading about lambda calculus. From the end of section 2.1 here http://www.toves.org/books/lambda/:

```
(λx.(λx.λy.x × y) 3 ((λz.x + z) 2)) 1   ⇒   (λx.λy.x × y) 3 ((λz.x + z) 2)   where x = 1
⇒   (λy.x × y) ((λz.x + z) 2)   where x = 3
⇒   x × y   where x = 3 and y = (λz.x + z) 2
⇒   x × y   where x = 3 and y = x + z and z = 2
⇒   x × y   where x = 3 and y = 5 and z = 2
⇒   15
```

It says

> In fact, though, y should attain the value 3 rather than 5 since the
>   first beta-reduction should plug 1 into x's spot in the expression.
>   For this reason, a lazy parameter must preserve the current variable
>   context with each reduction, remembering in this case that x = 3
>   within the expression λy.x × y but maintaining the fact that x = 1
>   outside the expression.

But I'm confused over the order of operations during the beta reduction. There explanation is, unfortunately, ambiguous. They could mean x should be 1 inside the (λx.λy.x × y) and then y = 3 because that's the next parameter to be passed in, and x is already set (feels wrong), or that we go my route below:

Do we agree that 
(λx.(λx.λy.x × y) 3 ((λz.x + z) 2)) 1
is the same as 
(λx.(λt.λy.t × y) 3 ((λz.**x** + z) 2)) 1

x is a bound here? Shouldn't it be 1?

That means when we reduce this:
(λt.λy.t × y) 3 ((λz.1 + z) 2)) x = 1
(λy.3 × y) ((λz.1 + z) 2)) x = 1, t = 3
3 × ((λz.1 + z) 2)) x = 1, t = 3, y = ((λz.1 + z) 2))
3 × ((λz.1 + z) 2)) x = 1, t = 3, y = ((λz.1 + z) 2)), z = 2
3 × (1 + 2) x = 1, t = 3, y = ((λz.1 + z) 2)), z = 2
3 x 3 = 9

Is that correct? Or did I reduce it incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the expression

```
(λx.(λx.λy.x × y) 3 ((λz.x + z) 2)) 1
```

which you correctly rewrote as

```
(λx.(λt.λy.t × y) 3 ((λz.x + z) 2)) 1
```

the `x` variable is bond to the outer lambda abstraction `λx`.
In fact there is no possibility that the reduction of the term `(λx.λy.x × y) 3` could change the term `(λz.x + z)` since it is in another branch of the redex tree.

### The book states it clearly that 15 is the wrong outcome

The example given is a **counterexample** of what would happen if a *Lazy evaluation* had be implemented naively.

Lazy evaluation is theoretically achieved by [normal order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Reduction_strategies), but that is just a theoretical construction with some practical drawback.
As such, strategies like *call-by-need* are used instead.

The book only wanted to show a possible, abstract, implementation of said evaluation strategy.

---

For reference, here a complete reduction using normal order of the expression.

```
(\x.(\x.\y.x * y) 3 ((\z.x + z) 2)) 1


          ()
         /  \
       \x    1
        | 
       ()
      /   \
    ()     ()
   /  \   /  \
 \x    3 \z   2
  |       |
 \y       +
  |      x z
  *
 x y



---------------------------------------

(\x.\y.x * y) 3 ((\z.1 + z) 2)


       ()
      /   \
    ()     ()
   /  \   /  \
 \x    3 \z   2
  |       |
 \y       +
  |      1 z
  *
 x y


---------------------------------------


\y.3 * y ((\z.1 + z) 2)


       ()
      /   \
    .'     ()
   /      /  \
 \y      \z   2
  |       |
  *       +
 3 y     1 z

---------------------------------------


3 * ((\z.1 + z) 2)


     *
   /  \
  3   ()
     /  \
    \z   2
     |
     +
    1 z


---------------------------------------


3 * (1 + 2)


     *
   /  \
  3   1 + 2

---------------------------------------

3 * 3

  *
 / \
3   3

---------------------------------------

9
```

Comment: @Maragret Bloom did your answer get truncated? You end on "Check th". I get the answer 9, woudl love to see if you get this aswell

Comment: @Prof Ops, maybe wrong copy-paste. I got a nine too, and also the book IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

@MargaretBloom's tree visualization is awesome, and yes, the book is just demonstrating a potential pitfall.

I'll provide this as just another way to see the reductions.

```
(λx.(λx.λy.x × y) 3 ((λz.x + z) 2)) 1   →β x + z [x := 1]
(λx.(λx.λy.x × y) 3 ((λz.1 + z) 2)) 1
(λx.λy.x × y) 3 ((λz.1 + z) 2)          →β x × y [x := 3]
(λx.λy.3 × y) 3 ((λz.1 + z) 2)
(λy.3 × y) ((λz.1 + z) 2)               →β 3 × y [y := ((λz.1 + z) 2)]
(λy.3 × ((λz.1 + z) 2)) ((λz.1 + z) 2)
3 × ((λz.1 + z) 2)                      →β 1 + z [z := 2]
3 × ((λz.1 + 2) 2)
3 × (1 + 2)                             →β 1 + 2 [ 1 + 2 := 3 ]
3 × 3                                   →β 3 × 3 [ 3 × 3 := 9 ]
9
```

Comment: this is great too with the formatting hints (boldening). Thanks alot :)

Comment: Wish I could mark them both as answer but as Margaret was first and her trees are great, I'm going to have to give her the answer credit.

Comment: @Prof I'm happy to help. I agree, Margaret absolutely deserves credit for the correct answer tho. My answer is just meant to be supplemental to hers ^_^